Flutter DIO post call not starting only on a specific phone
My client is testing the application I developed, and we are facing a very weird issue. Last week everything worked fine. Today he told me he can't log in with any user. Even if he types a random email and password, he gets no errors. The loader never ends.
I tried to replicate the issue on my devices, but everything works fine for me. I can log in with the correct user, and if I try to use a random email or password, I get a toast message saying "login failed."
I sent him a build with a few logs saved into a file. I added logs before, during, and after the login process. What I noticed is that the last log is "login API called," which is the line just before the dio.post(/login) call. Then nothing happens—no logs of the request payload, no logs of timeout even after 30 seconds, no exception because the catch is never called (otherwise I would have seen a log and the error toast). That's very, very strange. Nothing has changed since last week, and it looks like this problem happens only on his phone.
Do you know if maybe it's Android that prevents the request from getting initialized? It's an HTTPS endpoint if that helps. I don't know what else I could try. I don't have access to his phone because we are working remotely, and I'm not able to reproduce the issue.
Any suggestions on what to check or a possible cause of this issue would be really appreciated.
Here's some code. The last log is "/rest/login called". Then nothing happens.
    try {
      LoggerUtils.logger?.i('/rest/login called');
      Response<dynamic> response = await dio.post('/rest/login', data: request);
      return ResponseSuccess(LoginResponse.fromJson(response.data));
    } catch (e) {
      LoggerUtils.logger?.e('/rest/login error ${e.toString()}');
      return ResponseFailure('Si è verificato un\'errore', e);
    }
  } 

The app is not on the play store yet, but I installed the same APK on multiple devices and it works fine (even for him until today actually).
